# Does rand() function in c follows non determinstc algorithm

Tags: c, algorithm

I want to know does rand() function in c programming follow non determinstc algorithm

Comment: On some level, all algorithms are deterministic. The `rand()` function will give the same values with the same seeds, like anything else. What's the reason you're asking?

Comment: @DanielH "On some level, all algorithms are deterministic" --> [Nondeterministic algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nondeterministic_algorithm) discusses nondeterministic ones.

Comment: @chux The opening paragraph of that article mentions concurrent algorithms, probabilistic ones, and NP-time algorithms. If you consider the scheduler as part of the algorithm, concurrent algorithms are just as deterministic as everything else; similarly, `rand()` *is* the RNG so it wouldn't make sense for it to be probabilistic. NP-time algorithms are a more abstract CS construct, not a thing you can run on actual hardware. The best we have for nondeterminism is hardware noise or occasionally QRNGs, which both use non-algorithmic sources of nondeterminism.

Comment: @DanielH  Disagree with the "all" in "all algorithms are deterministic". Too sweeping and general to be true.  Agree `rand()` should be deterministic.  In OP's case, it is reasonable for a learner to consider `rand()` is non-deterministic and some how uses things like hardware noise - yet C has specified it otherwise.

Comment: @chux To the best of our knowledge, except at the quantum scale, *physics itself* is deterministic. Certainly the computer science models we use when describing classical computers are deterministic. If you want nondeterminism you need to graft a black box random oracle onto our usual definition of computation.

Answer (score 5):

> Does rand() function in c follows non deterministic algorithm (?)

No. `int rand(void)` and `void srand(unsigned int seed)` work together to form a sequence of [pseudo-random](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandomness)
numbers.  Reseeding with `srand()` and the same seed will generate the same *deterministic* sequence.

> The `rand` function computes a sequence of pseudo-random integers in the range 0 to
>   `RAND_MAX`  C11dr §7.22.2.1 2
>
> The `srand` function uses the argument as a seed for a new sequence of pseudo-random numbers to be returned by subsequent calls to rand. If `srand` is then called with the same seed value, the sequence of pseudo-random numbers **shall be repeated**. If `rand` is called before any calls to `srand` have been made, the same sequence shall be generated as when `srand` is first called with a seed value of 1. §7.22.2.2 2

Note: this sequence may differ from compiler to compiler, yet within a given compilation the sequence is deterministic.

Comment: https://dzone.com/articles/nondeterministic-functions-in-mysql-ie-rand-can-su. But I read here that in sql rand is non-deterministic (so SQL is basically developed in c)

Comment: @AdnanSheikh [MySQL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MySQL) functions are not required to act like the same named C functions.  C's `rand()` returns an integer in the range `[0 ... RAND_MAX]`.  MySQL `rand()` returns a number `[0...1.0)`.  For authoritative C documentation, I recommend against using an article about another language's functions.